# I cant render any frame in blender

Tags: rendering

all of a sudden i cant render a frame or a sequence in blender
i tried to unstall blender from start but nothing changed
you can see that in the first image its rendering noramly and suddenly its stoped
[image]

its stope rendering
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome, you need to explain a bit more about the issue, the image looks like a finished frame. what shortcut or button are you using to render a sequence. the more info, the better

Comment: Hello, the shortcut That i use its F12 i try to use cycle engine and eve and its doens work at all , when i try to render 12 frames for exmaple , it's only render one frome but it's doesnt work at all . i hope you understand now better

Comment: F12 is to render the current frame, while CTRL + F12 is to render animation